# Unscrambling the pixels of a GoPro

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I'm curious if there are any algorithms that solve this type of problem:

Suppose you have a camera that captures what a human would see, a GoPro for instance. But suppose I uploaded video from it to my computer, and I see that all of the pixels are scrambled, every pixel teleports to a uniformly random location. If a pixel gets moved in one frame of the video, it should move to the same coordinates in every frame of the video. And suppose I have quite a lot of video of varying environments, but mostly it's the type of things that humans would see on a day-to-day basis. How would you go about unscrambling this?

My intuition says that you should find colors that are similar in the image and gradually pull them together. For example, suppose I'm looking at a grassy plain and the sky. Pulling together the blue with the other blue and the green with the other green should get the pixels more aligned. Or maybe you could pay special attention to colors that are rare. For instance, suppose my camera is pointed at the sun. Pulling together those pure white pixels should help me get closer to the answer. Sidenote, suppose this works, the image could still be flipped or rotated, squashed or stretched when unscrambled, it might be a challenge to get past that stage, would be very curious about possible insights about that.

I ask because the human brain operates on the "neurons that fire together wire together" principle. If you take a nerve from one finger and put it on another one, the signal unscrambles itself eventually and you still get the correct touch sensation. I feel like it might be possible that ideas behind an algorithm that would solve this might be able to do something like create specialized regions in deep learning networks, similar to how humans have specialized areas in their brains. Maybe not, but just a hunch. Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: What is the process that generates the scrambled images? Why do you believe that the scrambling is reversible?

Comment: *Are* these images shuffled pixels? Or is there additive noise? Or something else? Or a combination of sources of "scrambling"? Please [edit] to describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: It looks like some image encryption methods employ pixel swapping, so I doubt that this strategy will work (unless the images are trivially small). https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-020-09695-8

Comment: @Sycorax That's for single images though, my line of thought is that if you have a series of images from lots of go-pro type footage where each frame is a little bit different from the last frame, like what a human sees, you can unscramble. Unscrambling a single image without context is probably impossible if I had a guess.

Comment: Each pixel yields a synchronous time series.  Presumably, the series for spatially proximal pixels will tend to be more correlated than series for spatially separated pixels.  Thus, by measuring correlations you obtain a pseudometric.  *Find a minimal-distortion embedding into 2D.*  There are many ways to do that, but this problem has the advantage that you know the embedded pixels must fall on a rectangular grid and you even know its dimensions.  Of course there are many more considerations, but this approach ought to give you a good start.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the thoughtful comment. So that is kind of roughly along the lines of saying say hypothetically if a group of pixels change to the same colors at the same times (consistently for a while) pull them together, and the opposite (push)? Also the rectangularity thing is really helpful;  it would make it so the problem is just that it might be flipped in some way. At that point you might be able to use something like there might tend to be more green on the bottom half and more blue on the top half (sky and grass). So if that works, then it's just flipping across vert axis. :)